# Pass parameter to Struts2 Action to display view interchangeably

Tags: jsp, struts2

this is what I want to achieve I have three view i.e JSPs.Event.jsp,EventCancel.jsp and EventAdd.jsp.
I want only One action to display each of these jsps. So example if the Action name is EventAction then one passes a parameter such as EventAction.action?eventviewname=Event , the EventAction should then show Event.jsp and so on.
Now how do I configure my struts.xml to achieve this.
Thank you

Like so

            true
            /view/inetreports/${reportName}.jsp
            false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're after. You can do this:

```
<action name="foo-*" class="your.package.EventAction" method="display" >
   <result name="success">{1}.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Then you call http://server/context/foo-Event and the jsp that gets called is Event.jsp. If you call http://server/context/foo-EventCancel you get EventCancel.jsp.

Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: hmm.. thanks but isn't there a way one could dynamically change the view name in the struts.xml like so

Comment: Do you mean change the JSP it is pointing to? I'm not sure what you mean by "change the view name". Yes, you can dynamically change the JSP you are pointing to if that's what you mean.

Comment: I re-read your question I think that's what you are after. I revised my answer.